# How to make Angular CDK Drag and Drop Accessible with a Keyboard

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, keyboard, angular-cdk, accessible

Our app has a "Form Builder" where users build a form by dragging form fields onto it. I'm researching how we would make this keyboard accessible - such that a user could...

- grab a field by TAB'ing to it and hitting Enter
- move it using Arrow keys
- drop it by pressing Enter again

I have found no information on making CDK Drag and Drop operations accessible with a keyboard...

Has anyone done this successfully? Could anyone provide some pointers on a good place to start making it accessible in this way?

Comment: Hey @blogofsongs did you get answer for it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this directive to the element you want to drag with arrow keys and change `xV` and `yV` from in input box : `[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="{ x: xV, y:yV }"`